# Include html file in cached html file

Tags: caching, include-path, ssi, server-side-includes

I've created a quick cache system for my PHP website using .html files to cache pages. I  include the menu via a .shtml file hosted on my server, so every cached file has the following code:

```
<!--#include virtual="/menu.shtml" -->
```

Problem is it doesn't include anything, why?

I don't get it, it works if I copy/paste the source code from the cache into a new .html file.

Here is what I have in my .htaccess:

```
AddHandler server-parsed .html
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the line I had to include in my .htaccess:

```
SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
```

It might help others having the same server configuration.